# Deleting Lambda Doesn't Reset Version Number

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I'm working on a CloudFormation template and noticed an intricacy with Lambda that's new for me.  Here's a snippet:

```
  VersionLambdaRandom:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Version
    Properties:
      Description: Version testing.
      FunctionName: !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:${LambdaRandom}"
    DependsOn: LambdaRandom

  AliasLambdaRandom:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Alias
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:${LambdaRandom}"
      FunctionVersion: '1'
      Name: TestDeploymentAlias
    DependsOn: 
      - LambdaRandom
      - VersionLambdaRandom
```

In the process of spinning this stack up and down, which deletes both the Version and Alias along with the Random Lambda that is not included here, I've noticed the version number doesn't reset when I create the stack again.  Essentially, I'll create the stack again and will get a failure during the deployment along the lines of:

```
Function not found: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:<Acct#>:function:RandomLambdaFunction:1 (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 404; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException)
```

Looking in the console, I can see a version of the newly created function was created successfully; however, it's now at version 2 rather than version 1.  This seems like strange behavior to me since I completely deleted the stack, which includes deleting the lambda and the version.

What can I do to ensure the version I create when creating a stack always remains at one, besides switching the function name each time?

Comment: Why would you care about the version number? Reference the output of `AWS::Lambda::Version` instead.

Comment: Related: [where is AWS Lambda version stored?](https://acloud.guru/forums/aws-lambda/discussion/-LVK9wFq6JrCh-gvDIZm/where%20is%20aws%20lambda%20version%20saved)

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't delete the version?

Comment: @Marcin - replied.

Answer (score -1):

Lambda versions are **immutable**. That's the entire point of versioning - you can't change them once published, which includes deleting them. You have to delete your function as well to get read of its versions.

Comment: That's what I am doing.  Deleting the entire stack, which includes the lambda function, and the version numbering remains when I create the stack again.

Comment: @Franchise any update on this .I am facing same issue.After deleting the lambda version is not reset

Comment: OP clearly stated _In the process of spinning this stack up and down, which deletes both the Version and Alias_ as well as a clear title stating the lambda was deleted. While this answer may be true, it doesn't answer the actual question. Or, are you stating that a named lambda will always retain their prior version numbers, even when deleted and subsequently recreated?